# Bertrand's paradox extension question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am having trouble with the following math question:

Consider four boxes, each with three balls.

1. The first box has three gold balls.
2. The second box has two gold balls, and one black ball.
3. The third box has one gold ball, and two black balls.
4. The fourth box has no gold balls, and three black balls.

If I draw from a random box, and I get a gold ball, what is the probability that there are at least two gold balls in that box? What about exactly two or exactly three?

I thought that this problem is sort of similar to the Monty Hall problem, but then I found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_box_paradox, which is much more similar.

I thought that the probability calculation would just be like this:

For $P$(exactly two gold balls), after drawing one gold ball, we can eliminate box $4$, and only one box has exactly two gold balls, so the answer is just $1/3$. But apparently this is wrong? What's wrong with my reasoning?

For $P$(at least two balls), I thought it was $2/3$ because we can eliminate box $4$ and then $2$ of the $3$ boxes remaining have at least $2$. Is this correct then? And can I use similar reasoning for the last one?

Comment: I find it helps intuition to number the gold balls.  Thus $G_1,G_2,G_3$ are in the first box, $G_4,G_5$ are in the second, and so on.  All told there are $6$ gold balls, each of these being equally likely to be chosen (since the boxes have equal numbers of balls in them).  Thus each has a $\frac 16$ chance of being the one you picked...making the probability that you drew from the first box $\frac 12$, from the second, $\frac 13$ and from the third $\frac 16$.

Comment: Note:  the argument I used exploits the fact that each ball is equally likely to be drawn.  This would be false if, say, the boxes contained different numbers of balls.  The idea would still apply, but you'd have to compute the probability of each ball separately.

Comment: yes, they are all equally likely to be drawn. i forgot to mention that.

Comment: Well, I think you mean that the boxes are all equally likely to be chosen and that, once the box is chosen, each ball with that box is equally likely.  That happens to imply that each ball is equally likely because each box contains $3$ balls.  If one box had a trillion balls, and the others each had one, then the singletons would be far more likely to be drawn.

Comment: oh yes, that makes more sense.

Comment: so using your reasoning, P(box has exactly two) = 1/3, P(box has at least two) = 1/2 + 1/3 = 5/6, and P(box has exactly three) = 1/6 ? also what's wrong with my reasoning (eliminating box 4 based on given knowledge)?

Comment: What's wrong with your reasoning is which I said.  Drawing a gold ball is evidence that you drew from the first box.  Take an extreme case:  two boxes, first has $10^9+1$ gold balls.  Second has $10^9$ black balls and $1$ gold one.  If you randomly draw a gold ball you can be just about certain that it you picked the first box.

Answer (score 1):

No answer (yet) on "what's wrong with my reasoning" but a route to solve the problem.

There are $6$ gold balls in total and $5$ of them are located in a box that contains at least $2$ gold balls.

So the probability that you drew one of those is $\frac56$.

Likewise $2$ of them are located in a box that contains exactly $2$ gold balls and $3$ are located in a box with exactly $3$ gold boxes, leading to the probabilities $\frac26$ and $\frac36$.